"A good thing about still living in the house we grew up in"
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part II Cambridge Choir, chapter 16)

(A letter from Uncle Robert)


. . . We might pop up to Cambridge for evensong every now and then, though I'm not sure how your mum would feel about that.
Anyway, I've been racking my brains for a way to make you feel better. I decided to hunt down something of your father's - a good thing about still living in the house we grew up in! I found a shrivelled old conker he beat mine with . . .

I take the bold words/sentence to mean "a good thing about it is (that) I'm still living in the house we grew up in". It seems to be shortened language/way of speaking there, right?

No, the passage means that one benefit of still living in that house is that the possibility exists for finding things that belonged to former residents.
The “that it is possible to find” part is not said explicitly, but is implied.

Thank you. I don't think these words are a full sentence, though. I think the verb/predicate is missing there.

But nobody  guaranteed you that Jo Browning Wroe—or any other author—would produce dialogue in nothing but complete sentences. Heck, some middling author even put into the mouth of one of his characters, “A horse, a horse! My kingdom for a horse!” No verb there, and hence no sentence.

I see, you agree the predicate is missing there. That was, indeed, part of my question. Of course, all authors can write at their convenience ( e.g. Shakespeare who isn't a middling one for sure :))
